# Running multiple identical applications

Tags: windows, automation, windows-10, autoit

Tell me why it does not work? I searched, but did not find how to run several identical applications, so that you can then work with each separately.

The script works, starts the first window, moves it, then the second window starts and the first moves along the second coordinate, and the second one does not move. What is the problem?

```
Run('c:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\cpuz.exe')
$hWnd = WinWait("[TITLE:CPU-Z; INSTANCE:1]", "", 0)
If Not $hWnd Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Окно не найдено, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf
Sleep(400)
WinMove($hWnd, "", 0, 645)

Run('c:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\cpuz.exe')
$hWnd2 = WinWaitActive("[TITLE:CPU-Z; INSTANCE:2]", "", 0)
If Not $hWnd2 Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Окно не найдено, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf
Sleep(400)
WinMove($hWnd2, "", 405, 645)
```

How to correctly write such a script?

Comment: Maybe get the pid from Run() and use it to get the proper hWnd? [ref](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/130252-need-help-getting-hwnd-using-pid/)

Comment: In WinWait a timeout of "0" make no sense. You may use something like 15. In your second statement I would also use WinWait (not WinWaitActive). After getting the window you may use WinActivate.

Comment: @ReFran yes, but I put 0 because The program can spend different time on loading

Comment: If you set to 0 there is no wait time. You have to use a higher wait time like 30 seconds. During this wait time the system is polled ca. every 250 milliseconds to see if the requested programm is started. After 30 sec. the wait/poll process will be finished and you have to take care of the result (sucess or failure)

Comment: @ReFran, 0 means no **timeout**, check [documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm). It's identical to "won't proceed until window exist" and can be easily checked with `WinWait("Garbage_not_matching_any_title", "", 0)`, so current usage is just fine

Comment: @ReFran All the same it does not work, even if I put a 10-second timeout, it overrides the first window instead of the second one, for some reason it does not index the second variable $hWnd2 and so it does not work as I need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...and the second one does not move. What is the problem?

Script generates identical `$hWnd` and `$hWnd2` tied to the initial window, which you can check by outputting variables with `MsgBox()` or `_DebugOut()` or whatever you like. Looks like **INSTANCE** property doesn't work well in current scenario, so `WinWait()` searches window using title only and the second call finds the same window as the first one.

> How to correctly write such a script?

Well, I have less than one week of AutoIt experience, so don't hit me hard, but here is my version:

```
Run('c:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\cpuz.exe')

Global $hWnd = WinWait("CPU-Z", "", 0)
If Not $hWnd Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Окно не найдено, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf
Sleep(400)
WinMove($hWnd, "", 0, 645)

Run('c:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\cpuz.exe')
Global $hWnd2 = Null

;wait until there are two windows with the same title
Do
Sleep(10)
Global $aList = WinList("CPU-Z")
Until $aList[0][0] > 1 

For $i = 1 To $aList[0][0]
    If $aList[$i][1] <> $hWnd Then
        $hWnd2 = $aList[$i][1]
    EndIf
Next

If Not $hWnd2 Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Окно не найдено, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf
Sleep(400)
WinMove($hWnd2, "", 405, 645)
```

### EDIT

Bonus: packed repetitive part of the script into function for easy use with multiple windows:

```
Global $aKnownHandles[1]       ;array storing all known win handles
Global $iCounter = 0           ;keeps track of array size

AddInstance(0, 645)
AddInstance(405, 645)
AddInstance(810, 645)
AddInstance(1215, 645)

AddInstance(0, 345)
AddInstance(405, 345)
AddInstance(810, 345)
AddInstance(1215, 345)

AddInstance(0, 50)
AddInstance(405, 50)
AddInstance(810, 50)
AddInstance(1215, 50)

Func AddInstance($x, $y)
    Run('c:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\cpuz.exe')

    Do
        Sleep(1)
        Local $aWinList = WinList("CPU-Z")
    Until $aWinList[0][0] > $iCounter

    Local $hNewHandle = Null

    ;for each handle in list of windows ($aWinList)
    ;check if it matches any item in list of known handles ($aKnownHandles)
    ;If not, put handle into $hNewHandle variable
    For $i = 1 To $aWinList[0][0]
        Local $bHandleKnown = false
        For $j = 0 To $iCounter-1
            If $aWinList[$i][1] == $aKnownHandles[$j] Then
                $bHandleKnown = true
                ExitLoop
            EndIf
        Next

        If NOT $bHandleKnown Then
            $hNewHandle = $aWinList[$i][1]
            ExitLoop
        EndIf
    Next

    If Not $hNewHandle Then
        MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Окно не найдено, завершаем работу скрипта')
        Exit
    EndIf

    Sleep(400)
    WinMove($hNewHandle, "", $x, $y)

    ReDim $aKnownHandles[$iCounter+1]       ;resize array
    $aKnownHandles[$iCounter] = $hNewHandle ;add new handle to list of known
    $iCounter += 1                          ;update counter
EndFunc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but what if to me need to move two or more windows?, then what? I think this way will not work

Comment: Don't understand your concern. If you need to get handle for the third created window while knowing handles for two existing ones, algo is absolutely the same: get list of windows with the same title, compare their handles with known handles. One handle won't match any existing one, so it should be saved as `$hWnd3`. Generally speaking, if you have n known hanldes, then opened (n+1)-th window, compare list of discovered handles with list of known handles. One new handle matches newly opened window.

Comment: I did according to your analogy, but I do not find the third window, what am I doing wrong? https://pastebin.com/1QyRuwfV

Comment: Second `for` is malformed. 1) iterate over all windows with `For $i = 1 To $aList[0][0]` 2) compare window handles properly `$aList[$i][1] <> $hWnd AND $aList[$i][1] <> $hWnd2`.

Comment: BTW, if you need to handle a lot of windows, repetitive parts of the script can be easily packed into a function, so creating/moving dozen of windows won't be tedious. But for small number of instances having less complicated and thus more understandable code is preferred IMHO.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything indicates that I do not know the syntax of the language, but I initially did not learn the language and just make a script / baht to run the programs and move them across the display. Thank you for taking the time to me, but you interest me, how then will the handle comparison look like in the function?